Why does this date time format don't work?
How do I query this problem?
I want to insert a date time in this format in a column name called DateTime_Encoded using a where clause.
The format should be this one (mon dd yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmm AM (or PM).
This is my sample code
ALTER TABLE ClassSchedule
    ADD DateTime_Encoded DateTime ;

UPDATE ClassSchedule 
SET DateTime_Encoded = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 9))
WHERE COURSE_NO = 'CPE 222'


DATETIME in SQL Server is NOT a formatted string - it's a binary value stored in your table. If you need a particular date format - just simply use the CONVERT function when selecting the date/time from your table. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 - in your case, you'd most likely need CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 109) - that's easily done in your SELECT - do NOT store this as a string in the table - no need for that

As a side note, you really need to move the stuff on your 2012 instance to your 2019 instance. SQL Server 2012 reach end of life almost 2 years ago. It receives no more security updates. 2019, however, is still in mainstream support (though that ends this year).

You're converting a datetime value into a varchar value that might not be valid for implicit conversion to a datetime based on your localization settings, then attempting to convert it back to a datetime.
Just leave it as a date, eg
ALTER TABLE ClassSchedule
    ADD DateTime_Encoded DateTime ;

UPDATE ClassSchedule 
SET DateTime_Encoded =  GETDATE()
WHERE COURSE_NO = 'CPE 222'


but when I only  used (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 9)) the result is in correct format  (Apr  6 2024 10:34:34:120PM). However , when I applied the 'UPDATE' class the result will be in default( 2024-04-06 22:26:30.180)

Datetime values don't have a format.  They are binary types, not strings.  They only have a format when you convert them to varchar, and the conversion of datetime to and from varchar is controlled by your sessions localization settings.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
